# Does Chrome ignore warnings for a given domain or certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I'm using a wildcard certificate for two separate domains abc.com and xyz.com

It's a Self-Signed Cert and I'm getting NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

Will ignoring the warnings thrown by one domain (abc.com) cause Chrome to ignore the warnings thrown in the other domain (xyz.com) by the same certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings gets only ignored for the domain you've explicitly added the exception for. Otherwise bad attacks would be possible, like having a self-signed certificate with both "does-not-matter-if-secure.example.com" and "www.paypal.com" as subject alternative names and then using the fact that the user adds an exception for the first unimportant site to mount a man in the middle attack against www.paypal.com.